# How to get predicted class from randomLCA?

Tags: r, statistics

In poLCA I can save the output from an object and access the predicted re-classification of participants with the following codes:

```
library(poLCA)
library(randomLCA)
object <- poLCA(cbind(Var1, Var2, Var3)~1, dataframe)
object$predclass
```

However, what is the equivalence of $predclass in randomLCA()?  Or how can I compute the predicted class from the elements of a randomLCA function output?

I tried all the elements of output of randomLCA function but was unable to find the poLCA equivalence of $predclass

```
The following are elements of randomLCA() function
 names(results)
 [1] "fit"        "nclass"     "classp"     "outcomep"  
 [5] "se"         "np"         "nobs"       "logLik"    
 [9] "observed"   "fitted"     "deviance"   "classprob" 
[13] "bics"       "random"     "level2"     "byclass"   
[17] "blocksize"  "call"       "probit"     "quadpoints"
[21] "patterns"   "notrials"   "freq"
```

Comment: When using functions that are not base R functions please start the scripts with a call to `library(pkgname)` in order to load the packages needed.

Comment: Are you looking for `fitted`? There is a method for objects fit by `randomLCA`, the method `fitted.randomLCA`.